# iOS running application on iPad doesn't show iPad Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I have a problem when I try to launch my app on iPad. I have 2 storyboards, one for the iPhone and one for the iPad, but when i try to launch my app on the iPad, all I see is in the upper-left corner the views that I have in the iphone storyboard.
I am using xcode 5.1.1

Comment: Did you set your iPad-Storyboard in Target General-Settings?

Comment: Yes, I set it at Deployment info.

Comment: Also set the app to universal?